How to Retrieve Recovery Logs on Samsung A15 4G After Error Message?
After a recent Google play system update, I started getting the following message on boot:
Your phone couldn't start normally.
Despite this, my Samsung A15 4G boots up normally afterward. I want to retrieve the logs from that screen to investigate the issue further.
Does anyone know how I can access these logs or what steps I should take to troubleshoot this?
Thanks!

It is possible that the A/B system saved you. My guess is that the update was installed to the non-active partition and upon next reboot the system tried to boot from it and failed. Therefore the default partition wasn't updated and the system returned to the previous state in the different partition. But that is just a wild guess.

Zygisk somehow caused it and now I just figured out where the logs are I lost them until this happens again.

You forgot to mention that your phone is rooted with Magisk.

Yes, but Magisk wasn't the problem I just couldn't figure out how to get the log from the recovery screen.

The files are located in /cache/recovery. Once you are in recovery mode, you can use ADB to access the device and retrieve the logs by running the following command:
adb pull /cache/recovery/last_log last_log.log

This will pull the log file to your local machine.

Stock recovery ROMs to my knowledge only support adb sideload but not adb pull therefore that the device is rooted has a significant impact.
